# I messed up with display configuration system setting. How can I do a factory reset of the display configuration?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

While setting up dual monitor in Manjaro, I messed up with display configuration setting.

I went to “System Setting -> Display and Monitors -> Display Configuration” and then I dragged the screens and I messed up my screen resolution and not able to revert it back.

Are there any way to revert the changes or to do a factory reset of display settings?

[image]

Comment: Don't add info in comments. There is an EDIT button that you should use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset your screen configurations, you will have to delete the `kscreen` (KDE screen manager) configuration folder by running the following command in a terminal:

```bsh
rm -rf .local/share/kscreen/
```

This will reset all your screen resolution and layout configurations.
**NOTE**: This will also delete any other screen layouts.

Answer (score 2):

1. Removed local configurations for monitors with `rm .config/monitors.xml*`
2. I did a reconfigure of **gdm3** (gnome-display-manager) with:

   sudo systemctl start gdm3.service
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
3. Reboot with my notebook lid closed.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE all monitors are scaled together in ~/.config/kwinrc

```
[Effect-zoom]
InitialZoom=1.23
```